# Extract a substring from a path

Tags: python, string

I would like to extract two parts of the string (path).
In particular, I would like to have the part **a = "fds89gsa8asdfas0sgfsaajajgsf6shjksa6"** and the part **b = "arc-D41234"**.

```
path = "//users/ftac/tref/arc-D41234/fds89gsa8asdfas0sgfsaajajgsf6shjksa6"
a = path[-36:]
b = path[-47:-37]
```

I tried with slicing and was fine, the problem is that I have to repeat for various paths (in a for loop) and the part **"fds89gsa8asdfas0sgfsaajajgsf6shjksa6"** and also the part **"//users/ftac/tref/"** is not always with the same str length and with the same subfolder numbers.
The only thing is that I want to take the name of the last two subfolders.

Can someone help me, how can I solve this?

I think that the algorithm should be:

- Take the str **a** from the last character until the first (from the end) forward slash (**/**)
- Take the str **b** from the first (from the end) forward slash (**/**) until the second (from the end) forward slash (**/**)

Comment: Use pathlib's path. `from pathlib import Path; p = Path(path); fds89 = p.stem; arc = p.parent.stem;`. "fds89" will be "fds89gsa8asdfas0sgfsaajajgsf6shjksa6" and "arc" will be "arc-D41234"

Comment: @Shmack, just use `fds, arc = p.parts[-2:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the path like:

```
a = path.split('/')[-1]
b = path.split('/')[-2]
```

Comment: `.rsplit()` with `maxsplit` suits slightly better. `a, b = path.rsplit("/", 2)[-2:]` or `_, a, b = path.rsplit("/", 2)`